# Undefined reference to vtable using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, linker-errors, cmake-language

I'm new to Qt and I'm trying to do a simple VoIP application.
I use CMake and conan to get all packages and build the application. If I place all Qt related class headers and sources files on the same directory, I can compile without any problem, but when I move the header files to another directory I found linker problems. I don't know why because in CMakeLists.txt I declare the include directories (and is working fine for others classes not related to Qt), I feel it's something related to autoMOC.

### Project structure

```
|--include
|     |
|     |--client
|     |    |
|     |    |--views
|     |    |    |
|     |    |    |--loginwindow.ui
|     |    |    |--ui_loginwindow.h
|     |    |    |--mainwindow.ui
|     |    |    |--ui_mainwindow.h
|     |    |--Client.h
|     |    |--loginWindow.h
|     |    |--mainWindow.h
|     |    |--Profile.h
|     |--common
|     |
|     |--server
|     |
|--src
|   |
|   |--client
|   |   |
|   |   |--Controller
|   |   |--Model
|   |   |--View
|   |   |    |
|   |   |    |--loginWindow.cpp
|   |   |    |--mainWindow.cpp
|   |--common
|   |
|   |--server
|   |
```

I've ommited some directories content because the problem is not found there.

### CMakeLists.txt

```
if (${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} STREQUAL ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Prevented in-tree built. Please create a build directory outside of the source code and call cmake from there")
endif ()

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

project(babel)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17.4)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_definitions("-fPIC")

if(MSVC)
    set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}")
else()
    set(STANDARD_UNIX_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -g3 -Wextra -Wfatal-errors")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${STANDARD_UNIX_CXX_FLAGS}")
endif()

if (EXISTS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
    include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "No conanbuildinfo.cmake file found")
endif()

conan_basic_setup(KEEP_RPATHS)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

find_package(Qt5OpenGL CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Widgets CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Core CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Gui CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Network CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(portaudio REQUIRED)
find_package(Opus REQUIRED)
find_package(asio REQUIRED)

file(
        GLOB_RECURSE
        SOURCES_CLIENT
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/client/*.cpp
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/client/*.hpp
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/client/*.ui
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/resources.qrc
)
file(
        GLOB_RECURSE
        SOURCES_SERVER
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/server/*.cpp
)
file(
        GLOB_RECURSE
        SOURCES_COMMON
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/common/*.cpp
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/common/*.hpp
)
add_executable(babel_client ${SOURCES_CLIENT} ${SOURCES_COMMON})
install(TARGETS babel_client DESTINATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
target_link_libraries(
        babel_client
        Qt5::Widgets
        Qt5::Network
        Qt5::OpenGL
        Qt5::Core
        Qt5::Gui
        opus
        portaudio
)
target_include_directories(
        babel_client PRIVATE
        ${CONAN_INCLUDE_LIBS}
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/client
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/client/views
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/common
)
```

### loginWindow.h

```cpp
#ifndef LOGINWINDOW_H
#define LOGINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "mainWindow.h"
#include "views/ui_loginwindow.h"
#include <QKeyEvent>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class LoginWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class LoginWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    LoginWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~LoginWindow();

private slots:
    void on_loginButton_clicked();

protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *key);

private:
    Ui::LoginWindow *ui;
    MainWindow *mainWindow;
};
#endif // LOGINWINDOW_H
```

### loginWindow.cpp

```cpp
#include "loginWindow.h"
#include <QPixmap>

LoginWindow::LoginWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::LoginWindow)
{
    int picWidth;
    int picHeight;

    ui->setupUi(this);
    QPixmap pix(":/resources/babel.png");
    picWidth = ui->babelPicture->width();
    picHeight = ui->babelPicture->height();
    ui->babelPicture->setPixmap(pix.scaled(picWidth, picHeight, Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
    ui->statusbar->addPermanentWidget(ui->statusText);
    ui->loginButton->setDefault(true);
}

LoginWindow::~LoginWindow()
{
    delete (ui);
}

void LoginWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *key)
{
    if (key->key() == Qt::Key_Return)
        on_loginButton_clicked();
}

void LoginWindow::on_loginButton_clicked()
{
    QString user = ui->userField->text();
    QString pass = ui->passwordField->text();

    if (user == "test" && pass == "test") {
        ui->statusText->setText("Correct login");
        this->hide();
        mainWindow = new MainWindow(this);
        mainWindow->show();
    } else{
        ui->statusText->setText("Inorrect login");
    }

}
```

### mainWindow.h

```cpp
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "views/ui_mainwindow.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

### mainWindow.cpp

```cpp
#include "mainWindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

### Linker output

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/babel_client.dir/src/client/View/loginWindow.cpp.o: in function `LoginWindow::~LoginWindow()':
/home/bltksk/epitech/tek3/CPP/babel/src/client/View/loginWindow.cpp:20: undefined reference to `vtable for LoginWindow'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/babel_client.dir/src/client/View/loginWindow.cpp.o: in function `non-virtual thunk to LoginWindow::~LoginWindow()':
/home/bltksk/epitech/tek3/CPP/babel/src/client/View/loginWindow.cpp:23: undefined reference to `vtable for LoginWindow'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/babel_client.dir/src/client/View/loginWindow.cpp.o: in function `LoginWindow::LoginWindow(QWidget*)':
/home/bltksk/epitech/tek3/CPP/babel/src/client/View/loginWindow.cpp:6: undefined reference to `vtable for LoginWindow'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/babel_client.dir/src/client/View/mainWindow.cpp.o: in function `MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)':
/home/bltksk/epitech/tek3/CPP/babel/src/client/View/mainWindow.cpp:5: undefined reference to `vtable for MainWindow'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/babel_client.dir/src/client/View/mainWindow.cpp.o: in function `MainWindow::~MainWindow()':
/home/bltksk/epitech/tek3/CPP/babel/src/client/View/mainWindow.cpp:10: undefined reference to `vtable for MainWindow'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/babel_client.dir/src/client/View/mainWindow.cpp.o: in function `non-virtual thunk to MainWindow::~MainWindow()':
/home/bltksk/epitech/tek3/CPP/babel/src/client/View/mainWindow.cpp:13: undefined reference to `vtable for MainWindow'
```

As I've said on the introduction, if I place xxWindow.h and xxWindow.cpp on the same folder, the problem disappears, but when I place them on the include directory it doesn't link. I'm not a cmake expert, but it seems right to me. Any hint about the solution?

Comment: Using GLOB to construct lists of source files is an antipattern. The typical failure pattern is that CMake does not see new files.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I achieved to solve the problem.

In order to make AUTOUIC function correctly, we have to add all the headers that includes ui_*.h to the **sources** target and not only to the include path. This way automoc will correctly process the headers and it will be correctly linked.

In my case it is like this:

```
file(
        GLOB_RECURSE
        SOURCES_CLIENT
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/client/*.cpp
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/client/*.h
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/client/resources/resources.qrc
)
```

Also, remember to set CMAKE_AUTOUIC_SEARCH_PATHS (cmake version >3.9) with the path where .ui files are located, if not, there will be an AutoUic error.

I hope this will help somebody in the future.

Comment: One should never use `GLOB_RECURSE` without `CONFIGURE_DEPENDS`, but it's better not to use it at all.